# dismissViewControllerAnimated: moves my viewcontroller to initial controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I tried to mail from imageviewcontroller and it works properly and the mail is send with the captured image successfully. when the send button is pressed, the mailcomposeviewcontroller is dismissed and shows the intial controller used for login purpose, but actually it should move to the current view controller i.e., imageviewcontroller..

Code used in imageviewcontroller,

```
- (IBAction)mail_button:(id)sender
{

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

    composeViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
   // [composeViewController setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    composeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    // [composeViewController setToRecipients:@[@"example@email.com"]];
    [composeViewController setSubject:@"Dressface Mail"];
    [composeViewController setMessageBody:@"HI i am using dressface application its very awesome you too try this." isHTML:NO];
    UIImage *myimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
    NSData *imgdata = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myimage);
    [composeViewController addAttachmentData:imgdata mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Dressfaceimage"];
    [self presentViewController:composeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}


}

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        NSLog(@"Mail saved");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        NSLog(@"Mail sent");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

// Close the Mail Interface
[controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

Can anyone help me to dismiss the mailcomposeviewcontroller and go back to previous controller where the mail_button was placed.

Comment: It should go back to the previes ViewController, where are you calling it from? is that the ViewController you would like to go back to?

Comment: You could try `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: @Alladinian, yes first I tried "self" the same effect as the "controller"

Comment: @PiratM, yes it should go back to previous controller, but in my case it going to the login page,which is not the previous controller, I tried the same code in different classes it been working properly, but only in cameraviewcontroller class it behaviour is not normal

Comment: the above code didn't workout on simulator but working properly on device... thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write this line in delegate method to dismiss `MFMailComposeViewController`

```
[[controller presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: yes, tried the above code, again it pushes back to the login controller.

Comment: the above code didn't workout on simulator but working properly on device... thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't dismiss MFMailComposeViewController passed in didFinishWithResult method as it manages the mail composition view. You should instead call

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

as it will dismisses the view controller that was presented by the receiver, that is the view controller on which you presented MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: ya, tried your suggestion initially, it pushes back to the login controller

Comment: the above code didn't workout on simulator but working properly on device... thanks for your suggestions.